# Unable to run a V-model unit tests properly

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

I have been wondering why I am unable to do test a test for a V-model and what I am doing wrong.
This is my simple component:

```
<template>
  <p>Hello counter!! {{ modelValue }}</p>
  <button type="button" @click="buttonClicked">Click me</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  methods: {
    buttonClicked() {
      console.log("button clicked!!!");
      this.value = this.value + 1;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    value: {
      get() {
        return this.modelValue;
      },
      async set(value: any) {
        console.log("Passing!!!");
        this.$emit("update:modelValue", value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And my test:

```
import { nextTick } from "vue";
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";
import CounterView from "../CounterView.vue";

describe("CounterView", () => {
  it("should update v-model properly", async () => {
    let modelValue = 12;
    const wrapper = shallowMount(CounterView, {
      props: {
        modelValue,
      },
    });

    const button = wrapper.find<HTMLElement>("button");

    await button.element.click();

    await nextTick();

    expect(modelValue).toBe(13);
    expect(wrapper.vm.$props.modelValue).toBe(13);
  });
});
```

Neither these instructions are working:

- `expect(modelValue).toBe(13);`
- `expect(wrapper.vm.$props.modelValue).toBe(13);`

```
 FAIL  components/__tests__/CounterView.spec.ts > CounterView > should update v-model properly
AssertionError: expected 12 to be 13 // Object.is equality
 ❯ components/__tests__/CounterView.spec.ts:22:42
     20|
     21|     // expect(modelValue).toBe(13);
     22|     expect(wrapper.vm.$props.modelValue).toBe(13);
       |                                          ^
     23|   });
     24| });

  - Expected   "13"
  + Received   "12"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just deleted the answer I provided as it was wrong, you are going about testing the wrong way. if you need to test the prop has been updated that should be done in the parent. the only tests that should be carried out in this component are that the computed property emits the correct information on button click and another to check the correct text is displayed. if you need to change props then use [setProps](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#setprops) i suggest you take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okWjao-Y9Eo) to properly structure your tests

Comment: You shouldn't expect `$props.modelValue` to be updated. You're basically trying to test Vue here. More precisely, the testing lib's wrapper. Unit tests are all about testing that, given a particular input (prop value or user input) the component outputs as expected. You're trying to test that a particular output (emit) results into a change in input (prop). That's a test for the parent component (where you trigger the emit on the child and test the appropriate model was updated). Rule of thumb: ***never*** test Vue. Trust that it does work, and it has already been tested.

Comment: Thanks both. I will try that. Wrap the component in a parent a test the behavior there.

Comment: your template is invalid, you cant have multiple elements, you'll need to wrap them elements in a div

Comment: Interesting. Neither the compiler, nor the application in the browse is complaining about that.
And here you have a sample in VueJS 3 documentation with two elements inside a template: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#using-a-component
Anyway I can assure you the app is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys. I was doing the wrong approach.
I have prepared a parent component and from there it could be tested properly.

<-- CounterView test -->

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";
import ParentView from "../ParentView.vue";
import CounterView from "../CounterView.vue";

describe("CounterView", () => {
  it("should update v-model properly", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(ParentView, {});

    const parent = wrapper.findComponent(CounterView);

    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(parent.html()).toMatchSnapshot();

    await parent.find<HTMLButtonElement>("button").trigger("click");
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.counter).toBe(25);

    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

<-- Parent View -->

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CounterView v-model="counter"></CounterView>
  </div>
  `, }
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import CounterView from "./CounterView.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    CounterView,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 24,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```